# PrefixStyleSheet killing dropdowns on the "Picture Tools" tab?

Tags: 2010, richhtmlfield

I have a [RichHtmlField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms543472.aspx) where I am trying to limit what styles users can apply.  I've run into an issue where when I set the PrefixStyleSheet property it disables all of the dropdowns in my "Picture Tools" tab.  I specifically need the "Position" options available so that users can wrap text around images.

Is SharePoint doing this on purpose?  How do I go about enabling the "Position" dropdown options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weird, I had this exact same problem yesterday, with the exact same Ribbon command!

You basically need to copy the position styles from corev4 into your custom CSS stylesheet, and replace "ms-rte" with whatever you put in the PrefixStyleSheet property.

EDIT: Hint - take a vanilla RTE control (remove the PrefixStyleSheet attribute), add an image, position it, then look at the markup. A CSS class is added. Look for that, and the related ones (think there's about 6) and copy them.

Comment: This definitely isn't the first time you've asked a question quite soon after I resolved the same issue myself... you working at the same place? ;)

Comment: Anyone have details on exactly which CSS classes need to be copied over? I copied a few but can't seem to get it quite right.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the Image Position drop down menu styles from corev4.css to the site.css file.

```
.ms-rtePosition-1{
-ms-name:"Left";
float:left;
}
.ms-rtePosition-2{
-ms-name:"Right";
float:right;
}
.ms-rtePosition-3{
-ms-name:"Top";
vertical-align:text-top;
}
.ms-rtePosition-4{
-ms-name:"Middle";
vertical-align:middle;
}
.ms-rtePosition-5{
-ms-name:"Bottom";
vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
```

Worked fine for me after that.